# Jenkins pipeline can't checkout the correct submodule code

Tags: git, jenkins

Below is the checkout stage of my jenkins script. My goal is to checkout the code and its submodules based on the branch name. During the checkout process, it doesn't get the latest submodule code even though there are changes from the submodule code. May I know what additional configuration do I need to include in my script below. Thanks

stage('checkout')
{
steps
{

```
            checkout(
                [$class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: '*/drop1']],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                disableSubmodules: false,
                parentCredentials: true,
                recursiveSubmodules: true,
                reference: '',
                trackingSubmodules: false], [$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
                relativeTargetDir: '']],
                submoduleCfg: [],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://xxxxxxx.git', credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxx' ]]] 
            )

        }
    }
```

I have searched the entire universe and there is no answer.

Comment: You cannot do this with recursive clone, so don't try to do it with recursive clone. Instead, clone the main repository, then, *in* that repository, run `git submodule update --init --remote` or similar. (See the `git submodule` documentation for details and note that this rapidly becomes very complicated. What you're doing runs counter to the design goal of submodules.)

Comment: how can i do it on jenkins script?

Comment: I'm not a Jenkins expert. I could kludge something together with a Jenkinsfile and an explicit pipeline but you're much better off with advice from an actual Jenkins expert.